# Logistic regression, "sum" confidence interval

Tags: regression, logistic, confidence-interval

I have an existing fitted logit regression model.

Model:

$\hat{p}(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-\hat{\beta}x}}$

With parameter estimates $\hat{\beta}$, and observation $x$

Given a new set of datapoints $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ and $o_1,\ldots,o_n$, I want to construct a confidence interval for $E=\sum_i \hat{p}(x_i)$. To goal is to check if $O=\sum_i o_i$ is (not) significantly different.

For a single observation, you can construct a confidence interval for the probability quite easily. Given $\hat{\beta}$ is normally distributed, and the confidence interval for these estimates is ($\hat{\beta}_{0.025}, \hat{\beta}_{0.975}$), the confidence interval for the predictor is: ($\frac{1}{1 + e^{-\hat{\beta}_{0.025}x}}$, $\frac{1}{1 + e^{-\hat{\beta}_{0.975}x}}$).

Is there a good way to get the confidence interval for the "sum" of the predicted probabilities?

Comment: Ummm, $\hat{\beta}$ are not variables, they are parameter estimates. And $x$ is usually regarded as a matrix of independent variables (each observation includes both the DV and these IVs).

Comment: You're right. I think this edit makes things clear enough. In my case, $x$ is relatively simple, just the intercept and some observations as a vector.

Comment: It looks like you should instead be asking for a *prediction interval* for $O$, assuming your $o_i$ are the (binary) observations corresponding to the $x_i$. ($E$ itself has little direct relevance to your question; in particular, a CI for $E$ does *not* translate into an interval for $O$.)

Comment: Yes, the $o_i$ are binary observations. But given that you know the distribution of $\hat{p}$, and because the model parameters $\hat{B}$ are estimated from a much larger sample (in this case), wouldn't it make more sense to estimate an interval around E? Why doesn't it translate? I am tempted to just do a bootstrap interval and be done with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is to use a boot strapping approach, given the new set of data points, to construct a boot strap estimate and confidence interval for $\sum_i\hat p(x_i)$

```
set.seed(44)

#Pseudo Data
prob = .2
x = sort(rnorm(100))
y = rbinom(100,1,prob)

#Fit the logistic regression model
model = glm(y~x,family="binomial")

#More data arrives
x.new = rnorm(10000)

#The number of bootstrap samples
B = 10000

sum.p = rep(NA,)
for(i in 1:B){
    #Create a bootstrap sample
    x.boot = sample(x.new,length(x.new)*.1,replace=TRUE)        

    #Calculate the sum of p
    sum.p[i] = sum(1/(1+exp(-(model$coef[1]+model$coef[2]*x.boot))))
}

#Get the 2.5% and 97.5% quantile from the bootstrap estimator 
lower = quantile(sum.p,prob=.025)
upper = quantile(sum.p,prob=.975)

#Construct a 95% confidence interval
ci = c(lower,upper)
```

An alternative method would be to take a Bayesian approach and recaculate $\sum_i\hat p(x_i)$ for every sample of $\beta$ at every step of an MCMC type algorithm.  Then at the end of our MCMC we would have a sample of $\sum_i\hat p(x_i)^{(j)}$ for every $j^{th}$ step of the MCMC that we could take the quantiles of in order to obtain our 95% confidence interval for $\sum_i\hat p(x_i)$ .

## Using Scortchi's Suggestion here is the revised code:

```
#Scortchi's suggestion
set.seed(44)
prob = .2

#More data arrives
x.new = rnorm(10000)
y.new = rbinom(10000,1,prob)

#The number of bootstrap samples
B = 10000

sum.p = rep(NA,B)
for(i in 1:B){
    #Create a bootstrap sample
    index = sample(1:length(x.new),length(x.new)*.1,replace=TRUE)
    x.boot = x.new[index]       
    y.boot = y.new[index]

    model = glm(y.boot~x.boot,family="binomial")

    #Calculate the sum of p
    sum.p[i] = sum(1/(1+exp(-(model$coef[1]+model$coef[2]*x.boot))))
}

#Get the 2.5% and 97.5% quantile from the bootstrap estimator 
lower = quantile(sum.p,prob=.025)
upper = quantile(sum.p,prob=.975)

#Construct a 95% confidence interval
ci = c(lower,upper)
```

Now interestingly, the confidence interval from using Scortchi's suggestion results in

```
> ci
 2.5% 97.5% 
  174   223
```

where as using my original code we obtain the following:

```
> ci
    2.5%    97.5% 
242.4727 247.0230
```

So there is clearly a difference between the two methods.

Comment: Looks promising.  While I'm absorbing this, please tell me whether there's a missing "-" in the line below "#Calculate the sum of p".

Comment: Good catch. That would make my confidence interval look more reasonable too :)

Comment: @BabakP, correct me if I am wrong. Shouldn't the x.new be drawn from the same normal distribution rather than a binomial distribution?

Comment: You are 100% correct.  I was coding fast and didn't catch that mistake. I'll fix it up above.

Comment: This seems to be answering the question "What's the distribution of the sum of predicted probabilities given a randomly-drawn predictor vector & known coefficients?". I think the OP wanted to know how to transform uncertainty in estimated coefficients to uncertainty in the sum of predicted probabilities given a known predictor vector. Though @whuber's surely right in saying that what the OP ought to want to know is a prediction interval.

Comment: @Scortchi, I guess I do not get that interpretation when I read the question since they state that they have parameter estimates $\hat \beta$ and $x$.  Never the less, if you want to change it to what you are saying then just make the simple adjustment of re-estimating the model parameters each time inside of the for-loop with each bootstrap sample. Not sure why we need to fuss with this anyway though.

Comment: @BabakP - I see Scortchi's point and, being clumsy with R, I would love to see exactly how you would make the adjustment you described.

Comment: I'll add it above

Comment: Now what you're doing is re-fitting the model to a new random predictor matrix in each simulation step. What you want to be doing is this:
(1) Fit a logistic regression model to the original observations & predictor matrix.
(2) Use the fitted probabilities from Step 1 to generate a simulated sample of observations for the original predictor matrix.
(3) Fit a new model to the simulated data from Step 2.
(4) Get predicted probabilities for the new predictor matrix using fits from Step 3 & sum them.
(5) Repeat Steps 2 to 4 many times & see the distribution of the sum of predicted probabilities.

Comment: Maybe this is me not interpretting the question correctly, but the question states "Given a new set of datapoints $x_1,...,x_n$ and $o_1,...,o_n$, I want to construct a confidence interval for ..." so we are no longer using the same data that we started with but new $X$ and new $O$.  And even worse, if the original observed data $X\in(0,.3)$ and the new data $X_{\text{new}}\in(.6,1)$ then the original logistic regression is going to do extremely poorly at predicting these new values.

Comment: The point of his mentioning the first model is that he wants to use it to predict probabilities for the new data-set - easy enough, but he also wants to put a confidence interval around the sum of those predicted probabilities. (He also seems to think he can learn something from comparing that to the observations, but as @whuber pointed out, you'd need a prediction interval for that, not a confidence interval). You're right of course that extrapolating too far from the original predictor set is dodgy - it requires confidence in the form of the model.